# WrappedApp created new store with withRedux(MyApp) { initialState: undefined, initialStateFromGSPorGSSR: undefined }

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I trying for create multi routs with express and next.js.

I run `npm run export` but Displays the following message.

> next export
>
> info  - using build directory:
> C:_PROJECT.next info  - Copying "static
> build" directory info  - Launching 3 workers info  - Copying "public"
> directory [=   ] info  - undefined (0/5)4. WrappedApp created new
> store with withRedux(MyApp) { initialState: undefined,
> initialStateFromGSPorGSSR: undefined } [    ] info  - undefined
> (1/5)4. WrappedApp created new store with withRedux(MyApp) {
> initialState: undefined, initialStateFromGSPorGSSR: undefined } info
>
> - undefined (5/5) Export successful

**_app.js**

```
import '../styles/globals.scss';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import theme from '../constants/multiTheme';
import { ThemeProvider, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core'
import RTL from '../hoc/RTL'
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from '@material-ui/pickers'
import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/jalaali'
import jMoment from 'moment-jalaali'
import Layout from '../layout/Layout'
import { wrapper } from '../store/store'
import Nprogress from 'nprogress'
import Router from 'next/router';
import LayoutProfile from '../components/layout-profile/LayoutProfile';
import toastr from 'toastr';
import SimpleReactLightbox from 'simple-react-lightbox'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'


jMoment.loadPersian({ dialect: 'persian-modern', usePersianDigits: true })

Router.onRouteChangeStart = () => Nprogress.start()
Router.onRouteChangeError = () => Nprogress.done()
Router.onRouteChangeComplete = () => Nprogress.done()


const useStyle = makeStyles({
    root: {
        '& .MuiTextField-root': {
            width: '100%'
        },
        '& .MuiOutlinedInput-input': {
            padding: '16px 14px',
            fontSize: 14,
            outline: 'none'
        },
        '& .MuiSelect-selectMenu': {
            overflow: 'unset'
        },
        '& .MuiFormControl-root': {
            width: '100%'
        },
        '& .MuiStepLabel-label:not(.MuiStepLabel-active)': {
            [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
                display: 'none'
            }
        }
    }
})

toastr.options = {
    "positionClass": "toast-bottom-left"
}

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, router }) {
    const state = useSelector(state => state)

    const { pathname } = router;
    useEffect(() => {
        
        // Remove the server-side injected CSS.
        const jssStyles = document.querySelector('#jss-server-side')
        if (jssStyles) {
            jssStyles.parentElement.removeChild(jssStyles)
        }
    }, [])
    const styles = useStyle()
    return (
        <RTL>
            <SimpleReactLightbox>
                <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils} locale="fa">
                        <div className={styles.root}>
                            {
                                !pathname.startsWith('/user') ?
                                    <Layout>
                                        <Component {...pageProps} />
                                    </Layout> :
                                    <LayoutProfile>
                                        {
                                            state.userInfo.userInfo===null?"":<Component {...pageProps} />
                                        }
                                    </LayoutProfile>
                            }

                        </div>
                    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
                </ThemeProvider>
            </SimpleReactLightbox>
        </RTL>
    )
}

export default wrapper.withRedux(MyApp)
```

**server.js**

```
const next = require('next')
const port = 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !=='production';
const app = next({dev});
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().than(()=>{
    const server = express();
    server.get('/about-us',(req,res)=>{
        return app.render(req,res,'/about-us');
    })
    server.get('*',(req,res)=>{
        return handle(req,res);
    })
    server.listen(port , (err)=>{
        if(err) throw error;
        console.log(`Ready on http://localhost:${port}`)
    })
})
```

**store.js** :

```
  import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers, compose } from 'redux'
import userReducer from './reducers/userReducer'
import {createWrapper} from 'next-redux-wrapper';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import hardSet from 'redux-persist/lib/stateReconciler/autoMergeLevel2'
import userInfoReducer from './reducers/userInfoReducer'

const composeEnhancers =
    (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' &&
        global.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__) ||
    compose

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    userInfo : userInfoReducer
})

const makeStore = ({ isServer }) => {
    if (isServer) {
        return createStore(
            rootReducer,
            composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk))
        )
    } else {
        const { persistStore, persistReducer } = require('redux-persist')
        const storage = require('redux-persist/lib/storage').default

        const persistConfig = {
            key: 'root',
            storage,
            stateReconciler: hardSet
        }

        const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

        const store = createStore(
            persistedReducer,
            composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk))
        )

        store.__persistor = persistStore(store)

        return store
    }
}

export const wrapper = createWrapper(makeStore, { debug: true })
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the changes caused by the getInitialProps and getServerSideProps. It is undefined because you are not using redux in both of these.

I was using redux in the GSSR. It showed me this message

```
4. WrappedApp created new store with withRedux(MyApp) {   
initialState: undefined,   
initialStateFromGSPorGSSR: {
ui: { loader: false, snackbar: [Object] },
login: { isLogin: false, togglePage: false },
me: { currentPage: 'Profile' }   
 } 
}
```